# How to save the logs with TimedRotatingFileHandler at the specific hour?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

How to set up the method associated with the the file handler rotation in order to rotate the files at the specific time for instance 3:00 AM? I assumed that it should be resolved with the `atTime` param ?

```
TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that's what the parameter `atTime` does. You still have to put the `when` argument to `"midnight"` as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):

> You can use the `when` to specify the type of interval. [...]
> 'midnight': Roll over at midnight, if `atTime` not specified, else at time `atTime`.

For your use case, do:

```py
import datetime
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    "log.txt",
    when="midnight",  # it tells to roll rover at atTime
    atTime=datetime.time(3, 0, 0)  # 3 AM
)

logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info("This is a message")
```